# How to create a link to downlad a static csv file from /public/csv directory in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Regarding the React application, i have the list of static csv files in the /public/csv directory. Then, a js file has the following code:

`<a href="/public/csv/file.csv" download>Download</a>`

This works locally for downloading the csv file, however, it doesn't work when the app is deployed to the server.

Could you please suggest how to download a static file from the public/csv folder in React?

My directory structure:

```
Project
 - build
   - index.html
   - main.js
 - public
   - csv << the target csv file to be downloaded
 -  src
   - index.js
   - App.js
 - package.json
 - webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Could you try `href="./public/csv/file.csv"` ?

Comment: Try `<a href="csv/file.csv" download>Download</a>` because after you do `npm run build`, everything inside `public` is directly available inside the `build` directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/csv/file.csv"} download>Download CSV</a>
```

Old question but I thought I would post the answer, to access the public directory in React from JavaScript you need to use the "process.env.PUBLIC_URL" environment variable.